# How to hide bottom nav bar in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have bottom nav bar define in the Main activity. I have three fragments linked with BottomNavigation bar in fragments I have recycler view so I want to hide BottomNavigation  bar when RecyclerView scrolls down and shows when RecyclerView scrolls up.
My problem is how can I access BottomNavigation bar in fragments because it is defined in MainActivity.

This is my code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/chooseLocation"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:hint="Search here"
        android:textColorHint="#9e9e9e"
        android:textColor="#000"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:background="@drawable/search_edit_text"
        android:paddingEnd="6dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
    android:background="#fff"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_check"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_check"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Tab1Fragment"
android:background="#fff">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/purchasedBook"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how my fragments are defined as there is no bottom nav bar in any fragments so how can I access bottom nav bar in fragments.

Someone, please let me know any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**To access your BottomNavigationView from within the fragments use the following code:**

```js
BottomNavigationView navBar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
```

Comment: Thanks bro ,that worked fine but bottom nav bar is hiding instantly how can I hide it smoothly.

Comment: Did you impelement the `BottomNavigationViewBehavior` as suggested by @Brahma Datta?

Comment: both of your solution are working absolutely fine but to get access of bottom nav bar in my fragments I am using your solution as it is very short and simple.

Comment: It will make the tight Coupling between Fragment and Android

Comment: You can make it invisible when within a certain fragment, but when you click back it remains invisible. How can that be fixed?

Comment: @JMB out of the blue i would say that you could handle the onBackPressed method in the calling activity and set the visibility there. Then delegate the processing to the fragment.

Comment: I did just that, but it seems a little bit choppy the code. Wasn't sure if there was a cleaner way to do it. I called the method in the fragment which I wrote in the Activity, but then onbackpressed I have to add code to make the BottomNavView visible again because if not it stays GONE.

Answer (score 41):

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
   if(destination.id == R.id.full_screen_destination) {
       
       bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE
   } else {
       
       bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
   }
}
```

Do this in the main activity.
Here `R.id.full_screen_destination` is id of the fragment in navigation fragment.

Answer (score 4):

As the fragment is always inside an activity and you can call `getActivity()` in fragment to access objects that already exist in the activity. So you can do this:

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//...
   Toolbar toolbar;
//...
   public Toolbar getNav() {
      return toolbar;
   }
//...
}
```

**Fragment**

```
//...
if(getActivity() != null && getActivity instanceOf MainActivity)
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getNav().setVisiblity(View.GONE);
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Add this line in the BottomNavigationView in Xml

> app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"

And Implement this BottomNavigation behavior using CoOrdinator Layout and you can hide or show the view using the scroll listeners.

```
public class BottomNavigationViewBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<BottomNavigationView> {

private int height;

@Override
public boolean onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout parent, BottomNavigationView child, int layoutDirection) {
    height = child.getHeight();
    return super.onLayoutChild(parent, child, layoutDirection);
}

@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
                               BottomNavigationView child, @NonNull 
                               View directTargetChild, @NonNull View target,
                               int axes, int type)
{
    return axes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
}

@Override
public void onNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull BottomNavigationView child,
           @NonNull View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed,
           int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed, 
            @ViewCompat.NestedScrollType int type)
{
   if (dyConsumed > 0) {
       slideDown(child);
   } else if (dyConsumed < 0) {
       slideUp(child);
   }
}

private void slideUp(BottomNavigationView child) {
    child.clearAnimation();
    child.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(200);
}

private void slideDown(BottomNavigationView child) {
    child.clearAnimation();
    child.animate().translationY(height).setDuration(200);
}
```

}

Add this line code to your Activity where it contains bottom navigation

```
bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) 
bottomNavigationView .getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setBehavior(new BottomNavigationViewBehavior());
```

Try this and let me know Digvijay.Happy Coding.

Comment: ,How can I access this Bottom nav bar in my fragments

Comment: Haven't you implemented the bottom navigation bar in the MainActivity where the activity is shared by Fragments? @Digvijay

Comment: Hey if it's working then please accept my answer and upvote it, please. As it reaches more people @Digvijay

Comment: Bottom navbar is hiding instantly how can I make it hiding smoothly.

Comment: Use Delay concept on those listeners . It may fix that problem @Digvijay

Comment: I am using reyclerview.addonScrollListener() method let me know how can I add delay.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193622/discussion-between-brahma-datta-and-digvijay).

Comment: @BrahmaDatta I tried your code but nothing happens. I have a fragment with a recyclerview that gets get loaded when my bottomNavigationView menu item is clicked. Maybe I have to go deeper to check scrolling activity? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment has `onAttach()` method which give you context. So you have to create instance of activity using,

```
MainActivity mainActivity;
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mainActivity = (MainActivity)context;
}
```

Now make method with `boolean` param which hide and show bottom bar.

```
public void visibilityOfBottom(boolean isScroll){
  if(isScroll){

  // hide bottom bar

  } else{
   // show bottom bar
  }

}
```

Now access above method in fragment using `MainActivity` context by,

```
mainActivity.visibilityOfBottom(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin

Access the navigation view from a fragment

```
val navBar: BottomNavigationView = activity!!.findViewById(R.id.bottomBar)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found for hiding bottom navigator in V6
was making structure like this -

```
Stack Nav {
   Bottom Nav
   Screen 1
   Screen 2
   Screen 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your fragment. will hide the Bottom nav.

```
   AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
    chipNavigationBar = activity.findViewById(R.id.chipNavigation);
    chipNavigationBar.animate().translationY(chipNavigationBar.getHeight()).setDuration(1000);
```

Use this code :
when Scrolling down the Recyclerview to your fragment will hide the bottom navigation.
then when Scrolled Up it will show the Bottom nav.

```
private View view;
private AppCompatActivity activity;
private ChipNavigationBar chipNavigationBar;
//...............................................

@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
         hide_NavigationBar_adwhen_Scrolling();
        }
        return view;
    }

//...........................................................

private void hide_NavigationBar_adwhen_Scrolling() {
        activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
        chipNavigationBar = activity.findViewById(R.id.chipNavigation);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recylerView);
       recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (dy > 0) {//on_Scrolled_down
                //  chipNavigationBar.animate().translationY(200).setDuration(500);
               chipNavigationBar.animate().translationY(banner_ad_card_1.getHeight()).setDuration(1000);

            } else {//on_Scrolled_up
                 chipNavigationBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                chipNavigationBar.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(1000);
                //  chipNavigationBar.setItemSelected(R.id.home, true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
```

to

> BottomNavigationView

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

to

> RecyclerView